# MVC ASP.Net Dropdown List that can be typed into

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am working on a project and I need to have a drop down that lets users type into it.

This is because there is about 17000 records (company names) and the page takes a few seconds to start responding(TTFB) due to having to load so many records.

So once someone starts typing I want to fill the drop down with the records matching what the person is typing.

I have everything but the typing the dropdown figured out. Do any of you know how to allow that?

My code so far:

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyRecId, "Company", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CompanyRecId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyRecId)
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#CompanyRecId").change(function () {
            var text= $(this).text();
            var subItems = "";
            console.log("JSON activated");
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCompanyList", "Delivery")", {searchstring:text}, function (data) {
              $.each(data,function(index,item){
                subItems+="<option value='"+item.Value+"'>"+item.Text+"</option>"
              });
              $("#CompanyRecId").html(subItems)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCompanyList(string SearchString)
    {
        SelectList CompanyList = new SelectList(db.Companies.Where(s => s.CompanyRecID != 0).Where(s => s.Company1.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(SearchString.ToUpper())).OrderBy(s => s.Company1), "CompanyRecID", "Company1");
        return Json(CompanyList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you reinventing the wheel? you can use the [jQueryUI Autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for that, or any of a number of autocomplete widgets out there.

The only caveat i had with jQueryUI Autocomplete is that I had to set the selected value in a hidden field (on the `select` event) so it gets submitted with the form. Of course, you have to name the hidden field correctly.

Comment: Thank-you for the reply. With this method, how would I update the list? .change seems to only get called once the user has deselected the input field.

Comment: @JasonBluefire what do you mean by "update the list"? the widget sends a request to the server with the typed text on every keystroke (with some delay, to let the user type a few characters between requests), and shows the matching values returned from the server in a drop down. You don't have to do all the code you have now, the widget does that for you.

Comment: I figured it out using your answer and this web page: http://vijayt.com/Post/AutoComplete-TextBox-with-ASP.NET-MVC-and-jQuery